# javascript galary-the picture can't show

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, how can I show the image? When I run the web page, it only shows the two buttons but no image...Should I call the function inside my html?

```
<html>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
var photos=new Array()
var which=0
photos[0]='images/title.gif'
photos[1]='images/pinkrice.png'

function backward(){
if (which > 0){
    which=which-1
    document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which]
    }
}

function forward(){
if (which<photos.length-1){
    which=which+1
    document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which]
 }
}

</script>
<head><title>How to Play?</title></head>

<body>
    <h1>How to Play??</h1>
    <!--steps of how to play, add image here--> <br>
    <form>
    <input type="button" value="Back" onClick="backward()"> 
    <input type="button" value="Next" onClick="forward()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` tag shouldn’t be outside your `<head>` and `<body>` tags and stop using the `<center>` tag.

Comment: so I have to put the script inside the <head>

Comment: also, I have to add something in the <body> to call back the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Edited your code. Test this. Now are working. You need a container to show your image. document.images only store your images on cache. you need a tag to show. [Download files here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lugcbwwlgcnx045/STACKOVERFLOW.zip?dl=0)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>How to Play?</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"> 

var photos=new Array();
var which=0;
photos[0]='images/title.gif';
photos[1]='images/pinkrice.png';

function backward(){
if (which > 0){
which=which-1;
document.getElementById("SliderPhoto").src=photos[which];
}
}

function forward(){
if (which<photos.length-1){
 which=which+1;
document.getElementById("SliderPhoto").src=photos[which];
 }
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>How to Play??</h1>
<!--steps of how to play, add image here--> <br>
<img id="SliderPhoto" src="images/title.gif" />
<form>
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="backward()"> 
<input type="button" value="Next" onClick="forward()">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: the picture appear, however the js doesn't work after I click the button, no image is shown

Comment: Download the zip. It's so easy. Work fine here. I used internet explorer 10